# Disable/readonly select tag in html

Tags: html, select, readonly

How exactly can I go about making a select tag readonly. I've read that you can't set a select as readonly. I do that I can set it as disabled but... That is not an option. I would like the user to view the rest of the options in the select tag, but not be able to pick one of them..

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the point to allow user to see all options but don't allow him/her to select any of them?

Comment: I dunno dude. I'm just the programmer. Ask the stupid users. :-(

Comment: @Relborg, I laughed so hard that my collegues gave me a weird look.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

you can use disabled attribute.

for example.

```
<select >
  <option disabled="disabled" value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option disabled="disabled" value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I see.. set each options tag as disabled instead of disabling the entire select tag. Thanks for your help Saifuddin. Really appreciate it

Comment: This prevents the selected values from being submitted with the form, though.

Comment: @ButtleButkus Yes, you're right. Disabled elements in a form will not be submitted While The disabled attribute will not work with <input type="hidden"> so hidden field will be utilized for selected values instead.

Comment: XML can damage the human eye.  Element properties (minimized attributes), can be done in HTML like: `<option disabled value=audi>Audi</option>`

Answer (score 11):

assume that tag id="mySelectID", and jQuery is resident, then :

```
<script language="javascript">
// disable all the options that are not in use:
$("#mySelectID option").not(":selected").attr("disabled", "disabled");

// to remove readonly, enable them again:
$("#mySelectID option").not(":selected").attr("disabled", "");
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery now distinguishes between attributes and properties, so you can also do: `$(selector).prop('disabled', true)` Details: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 3):

You can make it fake-readonly by adding `style="pointer-events:none;"`

Answer (score 0):

I used the selected disabled values for the option tag.

It will serve the purpose of prompting the user to select an option and at the same time disabling that option.

Example:

```
<option selected disabled>-Select-</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://coderanch.com/t/469173/select-box-READONLY-true

if you want to disable the select box, then you can use a javascript code to enable it back before the form submits. So on the onsubmit event of the form, you can enable the select box so that its value is also submitted when the form is submitted...